# Images not taking size of div container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a page where there will be a header on the top and 4 images which will in total take up 100vh minus the height of the header:

[Screenshot of how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naQhi.png)

This is what I have tried:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.theater {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: calc(100vh - 102px);
}

.theater div {
  width: 50%;
}

.theater img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header class="flex-container">
    <h1>header</h1>
  </header>

  <section class="theater flex-container">
    <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/5e88BFi.jpg" alt="image"></div>
    <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/5e88BFi.jpg" alt="image"></div>
    <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/5e88BFi.jpg" alt="image"></div>
    <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/5e88BFi.jpg" alt="image"></div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

However, whatever I did, the image 'overflows' the div container.

I tried using object-fit to crop the images, however, that didn't work.

I'd be very grateful if someone helped me solve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: any reason you have height `height: calc(100vh - 102px);`

Comment: Yep, I want the 'section' part to take the rest of the screen height. 102px is the height of the header, so by subtracting it from 100vh, the flex container should take the rest of the screen height.

Comment: The issue is that the flex container really does take the rest of the screen height. However, the images do not 'listen' to the flex container or div. They ignore it.

Comment: I suggest you try with css grid, your requirement is a perfect fit for grid layouts and it will be easier than with flex.

Comment: I thought of using css grid earlier, I will give it a go.